# twitter style regex matching in java

Tags: java

I want to extract the words corresponding to "@" in string and save it in a list:

For example:

```
 "This is @crazy_boy crazy" should give ["crazy_boy"]

 "This is @crazy_boy crazy @foobar" should give ["crazy_boy","foobar"]

 "This statement is boring" should give [] //or whatever is an empty list
```

In python

```
  targets = re.findall(r'(?<=@)\w+', text)
```

The above use to do the trick.. but I am not very sure in java.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). You need to iterate through the matches, for example:

```
String input = "This is @crazy_boy crazy @foobar";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=@)\\w+").matcher(input);
while (matcher.find())
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Outputs:

```
crazy_boy
foobar
```